# How to schedule cron4j on Tomcat startup?

Tags: java, tomcat, cron4j

I want my web server (Tomcat 8.5) to send emails automatically once every day while it's running. So I configured a StartUp-Servlet in web.xml to run on server startup. When I test it in eclipse, I get the error `Starting Tomcat v8.5 Server at Localhost has encountered a problem. Server Tomcat was unable to start within 45 seconds...`

I know, this is something happening in eclipse, but it seems, that the startup doesn't finish, and my server will never be able to to other tasks as it's busy starting up... I want it to instantiate the scheduler, but then finish start up and run the scheduler 'in background'.

What is the right way to trigger the scheduler during server start?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this. I implement a ServletContextListener instead. web.xml looks like this:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>servlets.SendEmailJob</listener-class>
</listener>
```

and the Class:

```
public class SendEmailJob implements ServletContextListener {
    Scheduler scheduler = new Scheduler();

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        scheduler.schedule("* * * * *", new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //sendEmail() - time pattern not specified yet
            }
        });
        // Starts the scheduler.
        scheduler.start();
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        scheduler.stop();
        scheduler = null;
    }
}
```